# What kind of component initialization is that?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am beginner in react.
I want to know what kind of initialization is that in the below *Post* component? Is that a function?
Why there are not curly braces {} of the function or render function declared?

I want need to understand the code in more detail so that I can change it as my my requirements.
How do I add parameter to it and return the post based upon specific id.

```
import React from "react"
import Async from "react-async"

const loadPosts = () =>
 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(res => (res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res)))
    .then(res => res.json())

const Posts = () => (
  <Async promiseFn={loadPosts}>
    {({ data, error, isLoading }) => {
      if (isLoading) return <div>Fetching data... Please Wait</div>

      if (error) return <div>Something went wrong: ${error.message}</div>

      if (data){
          const responseData = data.map((post)=>{
            return(
              <div>
               <p> {post.title} </p>
               <hr />
               <h1> {post.body} </h1>
              </div>
            )
          })
        return(
          <div>
           {responseData}
          </div>
        )
       }
      return null
    }}
  </Async>

)

export default Posts
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a "fat" arrow function expression. It's an ES6 feature: https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc

A couple of things to be mindful of (among other things) are, there is no binding of "this" and function expressions are not hoisted like function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal functional component. You don't need a curly braces for an arrow function if you are just returning something without any statements.

```
const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
```

The above arrow function returns the sum of a and b to sum. The same goes for functional component.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **React Composition** concept, check it out [Here](https://dev.to/bouhm/thinking-in-react-component-composition-fp5).

Answer (score 1):

It's a fat arrow function which gives the ease of returning a component :

Either

```
const Posts = () => (
  <Async promiseFn={loadPosts}>
  </Async>
)
```

will return the Async Component ,

or

```
const Posts = () => {
return (
  <Async promiseFn={loadPosts}>
  </Async>
)  
};
```

So the first syntax is shorter and simpler, but both do the same thing, returning async component:

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts